# Angular translate: change the cookie name

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using angular translate plugin: https://github.com/angular-translate

I'd like to use cookiestorage. When store the preference using

```
$translateProvider.useCookieStorage();
```

I see that a new cookie is created and is named: ng_translate_lang_key.

Can I change the cookie name? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's a method `$translateProvider.storagePrefix()` which you can use for that.

Comment: So I should use like this?


    `$translateProvider.storagePrefix('defaultlocale');`

Comment: `defaultlocale` is the name of the prefix. It could be anything you want. But it's not meant to be the locale.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The actual default cookie created is `ng_translate_lang_key`. I'd like to have this named 'mylocalesetting'. I should use `$translateProvider.storagePrefix('mylocalesetting')` ?

Comment: Ah okay, so to change that value you have to use the `.storageKey()` method

Comment: `.storageKey()` method causes some error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` writes in the console. Why this could be happening?

Answer (score 3):

This should work in latest version,

storagePrefix : Adds prefix to the storageKey

```
// This is the module constant.
angular.module('pascalprecht.translate').constant('$STORAGE_KEY', 'NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY');

// and this is how you can change this constants in your app.config assuming that you they cookie key will be name 'locale'
$translateProvider.storageKey('locale');
```